# Why does a link load so much slower when using href instead of routerLink with angular 2+?

Tags: angular, angular5

I am building a webapplication with angular 2 that uses routes. Because i'm new to angular I used to link to another component with the `href` attribute like so:

```
<a href="localhost:4200/database/seed/1">link</a>
```

This works but this approach also makes the component take a whopping 3 and a half seconds to load!

When i do it the `routerLink` way like so:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/database/seed/',1]">link</a>
```

It takes under half a second to load.
I was wondering why this is so, both approaches basically do the same thing. They link to another page. Can anyone explain what causes the difference in loading speed? Thank you

Comment: when you use <a href="localhost:....", you are saying that the page was reloaded comply. When use <a [routerLink]... you are saying that the page change to show the component

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using href is causing your entire website to be reloaded.

When you use Angular's `router`, base components do not need to be reloaded (index.html, styles.css, app.component.html, etc.).

Comment: Along with that a quick confirmation in a browser's dev console should show everything that has to be loaded in comparing the two calls.

Answer (score 0):

**href**
      If you use href This kind of navigation every time you click the entire page is downloaded and angular app re initialised

When using href if you observe while navigating to the page it will filcker and as your application grow the flicker delay will be longer

If you inspect your network tab every time you click it will re download all the file include bundle.

**routerLink**
   When using routerLink it will download only the content of the page it will not Download Entire Application